# How to apply CSS filter saturate to SVG elements?

Tags: css, svg, filter

I have this svg composition:

```
<svg width="400" height="200">
  <circle id="circle-1" cx="50" cy="100" r="40"></circle>
  <circle id="circle-2" cx="150" cy="100" r="40"></circle>
</svg>
```

I would like to apply `filter: saturate(0.2)` to the second circle but the CSS filter property is not working.

Answer (score 2):

In SVG elements we have to use [SVG Color Matrix Transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix).

For the specific case we have to do:

```
<svg width="400" height="200">
  <filter id="saturate" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
     <feColorMatrix type="saturate" in="SourceGraphic" values="0.2"/>
  </filter>

  <circle id="circle-1" cx="50" cy="100" r="40" ></circle>
  <circle id="circle-2" cx="250" cy="100" r="40" filter="url(#saturate)"></circle>
</svg>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/dx947a36/19/

Comment: You should be able to do it directly from CSS Try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u96hfowd/)  in FF for instance. It's only that webkit and blink don't support it (while [they support having it set to the whole svg node](https://jsfiddle.net/u96hfowd/1/)...)

Comment: I just learned that you should add `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` (default to `linearRGB`) to the root `<svg>` in order to get the same result as the CSS `desaturate()`.